# How to open unity in game link in new window?

Tags: html, hyperlink

How to open unity in game link in new window?
i did this but link is not opening in new window.

```
  var links : String = "Paste your links here...";
    function OnMouseDown()

    {        
        Application.OpenURL(links);    
    }
```

i add this link in game:
https://plus.google.com/111021357549156810867

and after adding this code its not working.
" target="_blank"

how to open in new window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually no built-in support for opening a link in a new window. However, according to [this forum](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/32531/applicationopenurl-on-webplayer-to-open-in-a-new-t.html) you can use something as follows:

```
Application.ExternalEval("window.open(links,'Window title')");
```